# Finding common elements between tuples in a list in python

Tags: python, list

If I have a list `ts` of tuples in python:

```
ts = [(702,703), (703,704), (803,805), (803,806), (901,903), (902,903)]
```

How do I obtain a list containing common elements between 2 or more such tuples?

Assume that both the tuples in `ts` and the the elements in tuples are already numerically sorted.

For this example, the intended output should be:

```
ts_output = [703, 803, 903]
```

Below is my working so far:

```
ts = [(702,703), (703,704), (803,805), (803,806), (901,903), (902,903)]
ts = set(ts)

t1 = set(w for w,x in ts for y,z in ts if w == y) # t1 should only contain 803
print("t1: ", t1)

t2 = set(y for w,x in ts for y,z in ts if x == y) # t2 should only contain 703
print("t2: ", t2)

t3 = set(x for w,x in ts for y,z in ts if x == z) # t3 should only contain 903
print("t3: ", t3)
```

And this is the corresponding output:

```
t1: {803, 901, 902, 702, 703}
t2: {703}
t3: {704, 805, 806, 903, 703}
```

From above, only `t2` gave the intended output, but I'm not sure what happened to `t1` and `t3`.

You may use this alternative input to test your code, and it should give the exact same output:

```
 ts = [(701,703), (702,703), (703,704), (803,805), (803,806), (901,903), (902,903), (903,904)]
```

Comment: I think you are not making it very clear.

Comment: What if `(703, 703)` is a tuple in the list as well? What should the output for `[(702, 701), (703, 703)]` be?

Comment: That's exactly I was thinking @Elmex80s

Comment: @Elmex80s We assume that that will not happen. The data has been filtered for repeated numbers like `(703, 703)`. Also, elements in tuples will be ordered from smallest to largest, so `(702, 701)` will be reordered to `(701, 702)`. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Any of the answers qualify to solve your problem?

Comment: @Rahul Yup, thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import collections

ts = [(702,703), (703,704), (803,805), (803,806), (901,903), (902,903)]
flat_list = [item for sublist in ts for item in sublist]
duplicates = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(flat_list).items() if count > 1]
print(duplicates)
```

### Explanation:

Given your input, you first need to flat your list.

```
#1 Simple and pythonic
flat_list = [item
                for sublist in ts
                    for item in sublist]

#2 More efficient.
import itertools
flat_list = itertools.chain.from_iterable(ts)
```

In case of method #1 your `flat_list` will be `list` object in in case of method #2 it will be `generator` object. Both will behave same for iteration.

Now you can count the elements in your flat_list. If they are greater than 1 they are duplicates.

```
for item, count in collections.Counter(flat_list).items():
    if count > 1:
        print(item)
```

or you can use more pythonic list comprehension.

```
duplicates = [item
                 for item, count in collections.Counter(flat_list).items()
                     if count > 1]
```

Comment: import itertools; itertools.chain.from_iterable(ts) is faster than the list comprehension when merging any list or tuple of the list into single list or tuple.

Comment: agreed. But this is more pythonic. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

You need to flatten your list of tuples. You can do this using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> flat_list = list(chain(*ts))
>>> flat_list
>>> [702, 703, 703, 704, 803, 805, 803, 806, 901, 903, 902, 903]
```

Or you can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterables`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to do the same like, However this doesn't require iterable unpacking

```
>>> flat_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ts))
>>> flat_list
>>> [702, 703, 703, 704, 803, 805, 803, 806, 901, 903, 902, 903]
```

After this step you can use [`Collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count occurance of each element in flat list and filter once which occurs more than one.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(flat_list)
>>> c
>>> Counter({803: 2, 903: 2, 703: 2, 704: 1, 805: 1, 806: 1, 901: 1, 902: 1, 702: 1})
```

Then finally filter `c`

```
>>> [k for k,v in c.items() if v>1]
>>> [803, 903, 703]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ts = [(702,703), (703,704), (803,805), (803,806), (901,903), (902,903)]
>>> c = Counter(el for t in ts for el in t)
>>> [k for k in c if c[k] >= 2]
[703, 803, 903]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that solves it by only passing through once instead of twice and builds result as it goes (not sure if its faster or slower in practice for super large `ts`)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ts = [(702,703), (703,704), (803,805), (803,806), (901,903), (902,903)]
>>> def find_common(ts):
...   c = Counter()
...   for num in chain.from_iterable(ts):
...     c[num] += 1
...     if c[num] == 2:
...       yield num
... 
>>> list(find_common(ts))
[703, 803, 903]
```

And without `Counter`

```
>>> def find_common(ts):
...   seen, dupes = set(), set()
...   for num in chain.from_iterable(ts):
...     if num in seen and num not in dupes:
...       dupes.add(num)
...       yield num
...     seen.add(num)
>>> list(find_common(ts))
[703, 803, 903]
```